# Rectangle wont draw over a panel

Tags: c#, drawing, panel, rectangles

I need to draw a rectangle around the edge of a panel created dynamically during runtime. First of all, I get a color in hexa code. I am converting it into ARGB using a code I found here on stackoverflow in similiar question:

```
string color = *getting the hexa code*
int argb = Int32.Parse(color.Replace("#", ""), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
Color clr = Color.FromArgb(argb);
```

Now, I try to draw the rectangle using this code:

```
Graphics g = panel.CreateGraphics();
Pen p = new Pen(clr);
Rectangle r = new Rectangle(1, 1, 578, 38);
g.DrawRectangle(p, r);
```

But it does nothing, no rectangle appears.
This code is included in a part of code that creates the panel itself and populates it with some controls (Comboboxes, buttons etc.). Do I need to add the rectangle to the panel using something like `panel.Controls.Add(r);`? (Tried that, of course rectangle is not a control so it doesnt work)

Comment: what function are you doing the drawing in.

Comment: @MarkHall in a method that creates the panel. This method is located in public Form1().

Comment: try the  panels Paint event, see if that works for you. Also verify that you get a valid color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try shifting the Graphics drawing into the panels paint event, since you are creating these dynamicly an anonymous event handler should make it easy.

```
private void CreatePanel()
{
    Panel panel = new Panel();
    panel.Width = 600;
    panel.Height = 100;
    panel.Controls.Add(....);

    panel.Paint += (sender, e) =>
    {
        string color = "#FFE80000"; //*getting the hexa code*
        int argb = Int32.Parse(color.Replace("#", ""), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        Color clr = Color.FromArgb(argb);
        Pen p = new Pen(clr);
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(1, 1, 578, 38);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, r);
    };

    Controls.Add(panel);
}
```

Comment: I like this approach, it works like a charm. One question though: if I want to later remove this event handler, I cannot use an anonymous event handler, correct? How would I use the same code with a named event handler?